# The entity type DateCollection is not part of the model for the current context. How to fix this error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Before getting to the details I must say that I have come to realize that this error is not specific and can originate from different causes. Therefore I will be breaking down as much as I can here for you.

I recently tried to move a project that I have been working on into an older solution that utilizes .Net Framework 4.0. It is a website, not a web app. Naturally, before moving the project it worked fine, now when I try to access my data context from my business logic it fails giving the error "The entity type XXXXX is not part of the model for the current context."

- I am using database first, since the database was already created.
- My edmx diagram is drawn without error.

The problem lies in trying to access the data. I broke my code to debug chapelContext as shown in diagram below. I saw this most interesting occurrence.
[image: Image of error]

The tables that are displayed by chapelContext shows one of two things(in second column):

- A select query
- The text "System.Data.Entity.DbSet"

The working tables (Tables that brought back no errors) are those with the select query shown in the image above. All others showed a "The entity type XXXXX is not part of the model for the current context." error, as shown in the AttendanceStatus entity that I broke into in the image.

This is the error stacktrace that I picked up off my web page 
[image: Error stack trace]
With this I do hope you guys can help me solve this error.

Comment: Since you did a migration, my bet would be there is an issue with your connection string.

Comment: @Khan I checked database in server explorer and everything seemed fine there. I then copied that connection string to the project containing the edmx file. The error remains the same.